# Error generating angular static html on pre-existing app with Scully

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, scully

I've been trying to generate static HTML with Scully and I keep getting the same error. I've looked it up several times with no luck.

What can I do to make this work? If you need more information from me, please let me know and I will edit this page accordingly.

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'scully'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prescully', 'scully', 'postscully' ]
5 info lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~prescully: ngw@3.3.21
6 info lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: ngw@3.3.21
7 verbose lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\laragon\apptest\test2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib;C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: CWD: C:\laragon\apptest\test2
10 silly lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm scully --' ]
11 silly lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ngw@3.3.21~scully: Failed to exec scully script
13 verbose stack Error: ngw@3.3.21 scully: `npm scully --`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid ngw@3.3.21
15 verbose cwd C:\laragon\apptest\test2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "scully"
18 verbose node v14.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ngw@3.3.21 scully: `npm scully --`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ngw@3.3.21 scully script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```